# How to control timer with mousedown in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

My purpose is let user click on the button, when user click, the field shows 4, when user click and hold more than 1 sec, the field shows 4.5. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn").mousedown(function(e) {
                    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);   
                    this.downTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#inp").val("4.5");   
                    }, 1000);
                }).mouseup(function(e) {
                    clearTimeout(this.downTimer);

                    // if no the holding is less than 1 sec, 
                    // then nothing will be set, when mouseon, 4 is set to the field.
                    var el = document.getElementById('inp')
                    if(el.value == ""){
                        $("#inp").val("4");
                    }       
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="inp">
        <button id="btn">4</button>Good
    </body>
</html>
```

However, my code has limitations, when 4.5 is set, it can never be set back to 4. Is there anyway to solve this? I have a idea whcih is if I can control some variable that represent the timer, then I can use if condition to accomplish this task. Is this possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the condition `if(el.value == "")` will not be `true` because input field is not *empty* (it already has *"4.5"* value on `mouseup`)

The solution is pretty simple.
You have to set field value to `4` and `setTimeout` while *mouse is down*. Then clear the *timeout* on `mouseup`

```
var downTimer;
$("#btn").mousedown(function(e) {
    $("#inp").val("4"); 
    clearTimeout(downTimer);   
    downTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#inp").val("4.5");
    }, 1000);
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(downTimer);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4szhywf/)